# How to find files in directories with certain name using Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a project folder called `topfolder` and I want to find all files in all subfolders that match a certain pattern, e.g. when the folder contains `foo` anywhere in its name, I want to list all files inside it.

I tried something like:

```
gci .\topfolder -rec -filter *foo*
```

but it has two problems:

1. Only files actually containing `foo` will be listed (I want *any* file in foo-like folder).
2. Directories matching this filter will be part of the result set too.

Then I tried this:

```
gci .\topfolder\*foo* -include *.*
```

but that doesn't work at all - apparently wildcards match only a single segment of a path so that pattern will match `topfolder\foobar` but not `topfolder\subfolder\foobar`.

The only way I've found so far was to use Get-ChildItem twice, like this:

```
gci .\topfolder -rec -include *foo* | where { $_.psiscontainer } | gci
```

This works but it seems like a waste to call `gci` twice and I hope I just didn't find a right wildcard expression for something like `-Path`, `-Filter` or `-Include`.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 20):

I would use the Filter parameter instead of Include, it performs much fatser

```
gci .\topfolder -rec -filter *foo* | where { $_.psiscontainer } | gci
```

Comment: How is it different from my last example? Won't it be even slower than my attempt?

Comment: Sorry, I must have been blind ;)

Comment: Thanks that is a good optimization tip (I was not even sure what the difference is between -Include and -Filter), however, does that also mean that this task cannot be achieved using single gci only? I basically need the `.\toplevel\*foo*` match `toplevel\subfolder\foobar`. Does PowerShell work like that? The documentation says that "star matches zero or more characters" so I was hoping that the first star would match `subfolder\` and the second `bar` so that directory name as a whole would match. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Sorry, I've messed the formatting. Hope you can digest what I meant.

Comment: That's the way it works. If you filter folders then you need to list them to get their content, if you filter files you need to check their fullname (path) or directoryName properties and base your criteria on them. Sometimes the first method is suitable and sometimes the latter.

Comment: Thanks for a great pointer, `gci .\topfolder -r | where { $_.directoryname -like '*foo*' }` works like a charm. I think you can add that as an answer (if it has some performance implications, just mention them but it works fast enough for me).

Comment: During my experiments I found out this also works: `([io.directoryinfo](Resolve-Path .\topfolder).Path).getDirectories('*foo*','AllDirectories') | Select-Object -Property @{n='Path'; e={$_.FullName}} | gci`. Not sure how good or bad this solution is but it is another way to get the job done.

Comment: It looks like you've got this figured out, but I was wondering whether it's your intent to return files in `\topfolder\foobar\subfolder`. If for some reason you need to avoid that level of recursion, know that you can use something like `gci .\topfolder -r | where { $_.parent -match 'foo' }`.